Proof of zeta functional equation in Edwards
I'm trying to understand the first proof of the zeta functional equation given in Riemann's Zeta Function by H M Edwards. Referring to the excerpt from page 13 below, I'm stuck on how he derives the final equation (underlined in red) from the previous line using (as he says) the Cauchy Integral Formula. How does he do that?


The integrand before the red line can be written as $\frac{f(y)}{y - 0}$, where
$$f(y) = (-2\pi in-y)^{s-1}\cdot \frac{y}{e^y-1}$$
Note that $f$ has a removable singularity at $0$ with $f(0)=(-2\pi in)^{s-1}$, so the integrand is analytic throughout the disk $|y|\leq \varepsilon$. The Cauchy integral formula then gives
$$\int_{|y|=\varepsilon}\frac{f(y)}{y - 0}=2\pi i f(0)=2\pi i \cdot (-2\pi in)^{s-1}$$

My knowledge of complex analysis is epsilon, where 0<epsilon<"not very much". I spent hours on that problem yesterday to no avail. Now it seems obvious. Thanks.

@Peter4075 glad I could help :)
